# AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function:

Tags: python, flask

I am creating an app with python and flask. I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Albert\PycharmProjects\Carro\views_trips.py", line 10, in <module>
    def index():
  File "C:\Users\Albert\PycharmProjects\Carro\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\scaffold.py", line 439, in decorator
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Albert\PycharmProjects\Carro\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\scaffold.py", line 57, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Albert\PycharmProjects\Carro\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1090, in add_url_rule
    raise AssertionError(
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: index
```

I have only one route.

```
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, session, flash, url_for, send_from_directory
from app import app
from models import Trips, Users, Cars, db
import time
from helpers import *

from flask_bcrypt import check_password_hash

@app.route('/')
def index():
    nickname = 'Bertimaz'
    trip = Trips.query.filter_by(user_nickname=nickname).order_by(Trips.initialTime.desc()).first()
    user = Users.query.filter_by(nickname='Bertimaz')  # não ta achando usuario
    print(user.name)
    car = Cars.query.filter_by(plate=trip.car_plate)

    return render_template('home.html', titulo='Viagens', trip=trip, user=user, car=car)
```

It was able to run it before I started implementing my SQL alchemy models and I tried changing the index function name

Comment: it seems you have another function `index()` in some code. Maybe you have it in `helpers` and you have problem because you use `import *` . MAybe you should use normal `import helper` and later execute `helper.function()` instead `function()`

Comment: I found out. I was running the script with the routes instead of the flask .app

Comment: you could describe it with details as answer below - and later you can mark your answer as acccepted. It will be information that problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the file with the routes instead of the correct script below:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
   
from views_trips import *
from views_user import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ****init**.py**, import the *Falsk app* and assign the value to that app.

```
from flask import **app**, Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from app.config import Config

**app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)**

# DB
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
```

After you have these above entries, you can import the app as

```
from app import app
```

NOTE: Do not import the app in multiple py files.